# Res.Render is not a function error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, ibm-cloud

I am getting an "res.render is not a function error" in the Windows 10 Command Prompt when I try to run my node.js code.

What is causing this error and how can I get rid of it?

Here is my .js file:

```js
/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// HTTP request - duas alternativas
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

//chama o express, que abre o servidor
var express = require('express');

// create a new express server 
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    // print a message when the server starts listening
    console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});


app.get('/home1', function(res){
    http.get('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json', function(res){
  var body = '';
  res.on('data', function(chunk){
   body += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function(){
   var json = JSON.parse(body);
   var cotacao = json["bovespa"]["cotacao"];
   var CotacaoDolar= json["dolar"]["cotacao"];
   var VariacaoDolar=json["dolar"]["variacao"];
   var CotacaoEuro=json["euro"]["cotacao"];
   var VariacaoEuro=json["euro"]["variacao"];
   var Atualizacao=json["atualizacao"];
   
  
  res.render('cotacao.jade',{title:'Hey', message:'Sua cotação foi de'});
 
  
  });
 });
});
```

Error: [image: Error Scrren]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where jade is hooked into your Express app.  In order for `res.render()` to know about jade templates, you have to hook a jade handler into Express.

If jade is installed properly, you should be able to do this to hook it into Express:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

[Express doc for this](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

---

In addition, you have named two arguments in the same scope as `res`.  Change the name of the second one that is part of the `http.get()` so you can still access the higher scoped one that is the actual Express response object.

```
app.get('/home1', function (res) {
    http.get('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json', function (res2) {
        var body = '';
        res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res2.on('end', function () {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var cotacao = json["bovespa"]["cotacao"];
            var CotacaoDolar = json["dolar"]["cotacao"];
            var VariacaoDolar = json["dolar"]["variacao"];
            var CotacaoEuro = json["euro"]["cotacao"];
            var VariacaoEuro = json["euro"]["variacao"];
            var Atualizacao = json["atualizacao"];
            res.render('cotacao.jade', {
                title: 'Hey',
                message: 'Sua cotação foi de'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You're dealing with two sets of HTTP requests/responses.

One you are receiving:

> ```
> app.get('/home1', function(res){
> ```

and one you are making:

> ```
> http.get('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json', function(res){
> ```

… but you've given them both **the same variable name** (`res`) so one masks the other and prevents you from accessing it.

Change the name of one of them.