# Unable to access response object data outside the function in node js

Tags: node.js, synchronization, spotify

I am using node js and making a call to spotify API and receive the response in body object, as shown in below code:

```
    var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
    };
    request.get(options, function(error, res, body) {
          console.log(body)
    });
```

This gives me output:
[image]

But now when I try to access the body object outside the function I get undefined. I think the problem is that I am making an asynchronous call and so before the response is received the statements where I make use of body variable outside function are executed. But I am a bit confused about how to get to the solution.

Any help is appreciated

**Edit:**

```
    request.get(options, function(error, res, body) {
        console.log(body)
        response.render('user_account.html', {
                data: body
        })
    });
```

And it gives the output:

[image]

Comment: You are right, you can only access the `body` variable in the callback itself, or in a function that you pass the varible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @LucaKiebel Then what can I do to access it outside the function. I want to display the data on my html page. So, I tried to use `response.render()` and pass but then it gives the error that response.render() is not a function

Comment: Can you share more of that code block, that shows what part would produce the `response.render() is not a function` error?

Comment: @LucaKiebel I edited the question

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109203/res-render-is-not-a-function-error-in-node-js

Comment: @LucaKiebel Okay. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use promise.

You can try following:

```
const apiCall = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
    };
    request.get(options, function(error, res, body) {
          if(error) reject(error);
          console.log(body);
          resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

apiCall().then((body) => {
    // do your things here
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: It gives me error that `apiCall.then` is not a function

Comment: Sorry. Do apiCall().then. Edited my answer